# Is the Build Pipeline Trigger available in TFS on premise

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've got the latest update of TFS (Version 16.131.27701.1), this link seems to imply that the build pipeline trigger is available: [build pipeline triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/triggers?view=vsts&tabs=designer#build-completion-triggers)

It does not show up on the triggers page for a given build just the Scheduled option.

[triggers page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mu6W.png)

Is there something I need to enable or maybe I am misunderstanding the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature hasn't made its way on-prem yet. It's slated for "2019" (the next major release of TFS), per the [Features Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/) page.